# "Invalid length parameter passed to the RIGHT function" when selecting specific users in a DB

Tags: sql, function

I wasn't able to solve this by analyzing the other users here, who had the same problem. I am trying to create a view by selecting a specific set of users in a database with the following statement:

```
SELECT RIGHT([A_ACCOUNT], Charindex('\', Reverse([A_ACCOUNT])) - 1) AS
         Account_UserKey,
         Replace(Upper(Concat('APP_',R.A_DESCRIPTION)), ' ', '_')             AS
            Role_BusinessKey,
         'False'                                                        AS
            Disabled
FROM [db_application_company].[dbo].[ROLEASSIGN_P] RA
         INNER JOIN dbo.LOGIN_M AS LO
                 ON RA.I_LOGIN_M = LO.I_LOGIN_M
INNER JOIN dbo.ROLES_M R 
on R.I_ROLES_M = RA.I_ROLES_M 
WHERE LO.A_ACCOUNT!='' and R.A_DESCRIPTION not in ('', 'READ ONLY')
```

Since the error message is "*Msg 536, Level 16, State 2, Line 1*" and based on the post of other users, I assume that the issue is coming from the "-1" but I am not sure how to solve it.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Several product specific functions used.)

Comment: If you run the CHARINDEX as it's own column you'll probably get some examples where the result is an invalid number to use in the RIGHT statement. You can then look at the data that is causing this and decide how you want to resolve it

Comment: The problem with using charindex + left/right is that you need to handle cases where search string is not found in the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is no "\" in the string on which you are applying CHARINDEX, it could return 0. Then your RIGHT expression will become ([Account],0-1) and will throw error.

Could you try like this instead; it'll check if "\" is present, if not then it'll return the original string

```
case when Charindex('\',[A_ACCOUNT]) <= 0 then [A_ACCOUNT] else RIGHT([A_ACCOUNT], Charindex('\', Reverse([A_ACCOUNT])) - 1)
```